# Does genymotion emulate the same specs of the phone?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, virtual, genymotion

Let's say for example, I am running Samsung Galaxy S4 with API level 17 - 4.2.2

Do I really get the RAM and the processing power of that device ? Or Genymotion uses the full power of my CPU(intel i5) and ram (8gb)?

That is, if I happen to pick an old device and test a very modern game that uses extensive graphics, would it run slow ?

Comment: No, it can't realistically replicate things like processor or GPU power - depending on the exact operation and hosting vs. modeled system it might be slower, or even in select cases conceivably faster.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so it uses the power of the pc rather than the exact phone specs?